# How to search pattern in a file by Linux CLI?

Tags: regex, linux, search, sed, command-line-interface

I've got log file with lines like:

`07:44:24||||234.234.234.234|123.123.123.123|www.website.pl/some,site.html|a:0:{}`

How do I obtain only `www.website.pl/some,site.html` from all lines?

Can this be done with "sed" or other command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, with awk.

Simply process your file with

```
awk -F '|' '{print $7}'
```

A little transcript on your example line:

```
$ echo '07:44:24||||234.234.234.234|123.123.123.123|www.website.pl/some,site.html|a:0:{}' | awk -F '|' '{print $7}'
www.website.pl/some,site.html
```

**CAVEAT** This assumes there are no other pipes in your file *except* those used for delimters.

Answer (score 2):

**Cut** also supports delimiter and field(s) selection.

```
$ cut -d\| -f7
07:44:24||||234.234.234.234|123.123.123.123|www.website.pl/some,site.html|a:0:{}
www.website.pl/some,site.html
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you:

```
echo '07:44:24||||234.234.234.234|123.123.123.123|www.website.pl/some,site.html|a:0:{}'|
sed 's/^\(\([^|]*\)|\)\{7\}.*/\2/'
www.website.pl/some,site.html
```

Or if the sites all begin `www`:

```
echo '07:44:24||||234.234.234.234|123.123.123.123|www.website.pl/some,site.html|a:0:{}'|
sed 's/.*\(www[^|]*\).*/\1/'
www.website.pl/some,site.html
```